# Bing maps Streetside view in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, bing-maps

I am using [leaflet-bing-layer](https://github.com/digidem/leaflet-bing-layer) in my project. I am currently loading Aerial and Road views of Bing Maps. Now, I also want to load Bing maps Streetside view in my application similar to https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdkrelease/mapcontrol/isdk/setviewtostreetside#TS. How can I achieve that using leaflet's plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Streetside views are completely different from orthographic Mercator tile layers (it's a spherical panorama, not a flat projected image), and can't be displayed in leaflet. The only supported way to get streetside views is to use the bing map control (which should also support all the functionality and views Leaflet does).

Comment: Along with Bing Tiles, I also want to load other tiles also like [OpenStreetMaps](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=4/21.84/82.79) to fulfil a use-case where user can switch between multiple tiles layers in my application. I used leaflet as it provides an easy way to create any type of map tiles and add markup over them. 
Using bing map control, would I be able to use multiple different tiles?

Comment: Sure, you can easily load other tile layers using bing maps. Docs on tile layers here: https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdkrelease/mapcontrol/isdk/tilelayerpublicxyzoom. Note that you may want to check the terms of use of whatever tiles you're using as some mapping services prohibit the use of their services/tiles with other services due to licensing restrictions.